# Sphere Shading OpenGL

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am trying to shade a sphere.I have no idea where to start from. I calculated the vertices, and connected them by using GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, and I also drew the normals to each vertex. The problem is that I have no idea how to even start doing some shading/lighting. I am using OpeGL 3+. Here is some of my code:

Sphere's Vertices Calculations (I found online and implemented):

```
void CreateUnitSphere(int dtheta,int dphi) //dtheta, dphi angle
{

    GLdouble x,y,z;
    GLdouble magnitude=0;
    int no_vertice=-1;
    int n;
    int k;
    int theta,phi;
    const double PI = 3.1415926535897;
    GLdouble DTOR = (PI/180);//degrees to radians


    //setting the color to white
    for (k=0; k<10296*3; k+=1)
    {
        sphere_vertices[k].color[0] = 1.0f;
        sphere_vertices[k].color[1] = 1.0f;
        sphere_vertices[k].color[2] = 1.0f;
    }


   for (theta=-90;theta<=90-dtheta;theta+=dtheta) {
      for (phi=0;phi<=360-dphi;phi+=dphi) {


     x = cos(theta*DTOR) * cos(phi*DTOR);
     y = cos(theta*DTOR) * sin(phi*DTOR);
         z = sin(theta*DTOR);

    //calculating Vertex 1
    no_vertice+=1;
    sphere_vertices[no_vertice].position[0] = x;
    sphere_vertices[no_vertice].position[1] = y;
    sphere_vertices[no_vertice].position[2] = z;

         x = cos((theta+dtheta)*DTOR) * cos(phi*DTOR);
         y = cos((theta+dtheta)*DTOR) * sin(phi*DTOR);
         z = sin((theta+dtheta)*DTOR);

    //calculating Vertex 2
    no_vertice+=1;
    sphere_vertices[no_vertice].position[0] = x;
    sphere_vertices[no_vertice].position[1] = y;
    sphere_vertices[no_vertice].position[2] = z;

    x = cos((theta+dtheta)*DTOR) * cos((phi+dphi)*DTOR);
        y = cos((theta+dtheta)*DTOR) * sin((phi+dphi)*DTOR);
        z = sin((theta+dtheta)*DTOR);

    //calculating Vertex 3
    no_vertice+=1;
    sphere_vertices[no_vertice].position[0] = x;
    sphere_vertices[no_vertice].position[1] = y;
    sphere_vertices[no_vertice].position[2] = z;

        if (theta > -90 && theta < 90) {

            x = cos(theta*DTOR) * cos((phi+dphi)*DTOR);
            y = cos(theta*DTOR) * sin((phi+dphi)*DTOR);
            z = sin(theta*DTOR);

    //calculating Vertex 4
    no_vertice+=1;
    sphere_vertices[no_vertice].position[0] = x;
    sphere_vertices[no_vertice].position[1] = y;
    sphere_vertices[no_vertice].position[2] = z;

         }

    }

   }

no_vertice = -1;
int no_index=10296; 

//calculate normals and add them to the array of vertices
   for (no_vertice=0; no_vertice<=10296; no_vertice+=1) {

    no_index+=1;

    //getting the sphere's vertices
    x=sphere_vertices[no_vertice].position[0];
    y=sphere_vertices[no_vertice].position[1];
    z=sphere_vertices[no_vertice].position[2];

    //normalising vector "norm(Vertex - Center)"
    magnitude = sqrt((x*x) + (y*y) + (z*z));

    //adding the new vector (the one divided by the magnitude
    sphere_vertices[no_index].position[0] = (x/magnitude)/0.8;
    sphere_vertices[no_index].position[1] = (y/magnitude)/0.8;
    sphere_vertices[no_index].position[2] = (z/magnitude)/0.8;

    ///adding the vertex's normal (line drawing issue)
    no_index+=1;
    sphere_vertices[no_index].position[0] = sphere_vertices[no_vertice].position[0];
    sphere_vertices[no_index].position[1] = sphere_vertices[no_vertice].position[1];
    sphere_vertices[no_index].position[2] = sphere_vertices[no_vertice].position[2];

    }

}
```

[image: Here is my Sphere without the "GL_TRIANGLE_FAN", JUST "GL_LINE_STRIP"]

Here is my Sphere without the "GL_TRIANGLE_FAN", JUST "GL_LINE_STRIP"
and this is how I use "glDrawArrays" :

```
glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, 10296);
glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 10297, 30888);
```

From 0-10296 are the Sphere's Vertices.
From 10297-30888 are the Sphere's Normal Vertices.

Here is my Vertex file:

```
precision highp float;

in vec3 in_Position; //declare position
in vec3 in_Color;

// mvpmatrix is the result of multiplying the model, view, and projection matrices */
uniform mat4 mvpmatrix;
out vec3 ex_Color;

void main(void) {

// Multiply the mvp matrix by the vertex to obtain our final vertex position (mvp was created in *.cpp)

gl_Position = mvpmatrix * vec4(in_Position, 1.0);

ex_Color = in_Color;

}
```

and my Fragment file

```
#version 330
precision highp float;

in vec3 ex_Color;
out vec4 gl_FragColor;

void main(void) {

gl_FragColor = vec4(ex_Color,1.0);

}
```

Now I know that I need to pass the normals to the vertice and fragment shader, but how do I do that and how/where do I implement the light calculations, linear interpolation??
Thanks

Comment: Have you considered learning OpenGL by [following a tutorial](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_started#Tutorials_and_How_To_Guides)? It would be a lot easier on you than asking large, complex questions like "how do I do lighting?"

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to calculate the lighting in vertex shader and pass the vertex color to the fragment shader if you want a per-vertex lighting or pass the normal and light direction as the varying variables and calculate everything there for the per-pixel lighting.

The main trick here is that when you pass the normal to the fragment shader it is being interpolated between vertices for each fragment and as the result the shading is very smooth but also slower.

[Here is a very nice article to start with.](http://zach.in.tu-clausthal.de/teaching/cg_literatur/glsl_tutorial/index.html)

Comment: thanks. all these you mentioned can be done only using GLSL and modifying the vertex and fragment files?

Comment: probably yes. the only thing that you should also check is how to pass uniforms and attributes, but it seems to be very straightforward thing.